# Print out last 3 blogposts

Tags: posts, wp-query

From problem to problem, disco to disco :P

My template requires that i print out headlines of 3 last blogposts in the header of my template. Its single page layout so those blogposts will link to posts that will be on page anyway - just somewhere down the line...

Since im complete wordpress newbie - i've already required help with creating this whole single page layout:

[Single page theme](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/104725/single-page-theme)

[Modified home page query does not yield expected results](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/104763/modified-home-page-query-does-not-yield-expected-results)

Long story short - i created app hook, that changes original query to include all pages. These blogposts need to be taken care of before we get to parsing the pages.

What i tried - following some  examples i set up something like this:

```
            <?php
            $args = array( 
                'orderby' => 'ID', 
                'order' => 'DESC', 
                'post_type' => 'post',
                'post_status' => 'publish',
                );
            $children = get_pages($args);
            foreach( $children as $post ){
                setup_postdata($post);
                get_template_part( 'header', 'blogheader' );
            }
            wp_reset_postdata();
            ?>
```

Yes the query does not include the posts limit 3 - but so be it. What this gives me - exactly nothing. If i comment everything out from those args, then i get my main query. Even just one argument, like 'post_type' => 'post' - i get nothing.

This led me into thinking that all those args are just modifying the original main query, not creating new one. Fine. I replaced `get_pages($args)` with `new WP_Query( $args );`. Now i got funny results - whole load of posts - even though i actually have just one, original, "hello world" post. It prints out even posts that have no title (im guessing they are drafts or something, even though i have not created any draft blogposts).

So what i want - i thought that setting post_type to post will give me blogposts only - i was wrong. What parameters do i have to set to get only published blogposts, sorted by id?

Alan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were not passing any limit to the query.

```
    $args = array( 
        'posts_per_page' => 3, 
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'ignore_sticky_posts' => true
    );
    $children = new WP_Query($args);
    if ($children->have_posts()) {
      while ($children->have_posts()) {
        $children->the_post();
        // get_template_part( 'header', 'blogheader' ); // not on my server :)
      }
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
```

I made a couple of changes. You were querying for 'posts' with a function called `get_pages`. While that function does accept a `post_type` argument using `WP_Query` is neater.

I added `ignore_sticky_posts`. Without that you won't get the latest posts, you'll get sticky posts and then the latest ones.

I don't know what is in `header-blogheader.php` but it is possible that it is written in such a way that things still do not work.

Comment: blogheader only prints out the title and date of the blogpost. nothing else. Ill try your solution tomorrow. Thanks.

Comment: My concern is that variables like `$post` can get out of scope.

Comment: Tested - works like a charm. Can i get an explanation now please. Why does $children->have_posts() work and $children as $post does not?

Comment: With your code, that would work but not with `'post_type' => 'post',`. With my code you would need `foreach ($children->posts as $post) {` but it should work.

Comment: Hmm that made no sense to me. In my post i also said that i replaced get_posts for new WP_Query( $args ) - so our args and query were pretty much the same. Your loop got posts though and mine didnt. Thats what i was wondering about. Why your loop worked and mine didnt.

Comment: Look at `var_dump($children);` and see if it doesn't help. Your posts are not directly in `$children` but in `$children->posts`.